# Problem in a macro definition (plain TeX)

Tags: macros, plain-tex

I'm trying to write a `\multicenter` macro that acts as `\centerline`, except that it splits the text in different lines whenever it encounters the command `\\`.  For example,  `\multicenter{ciao\\a\\tutti!}` should be equivalent to `\centerline{ciao}\centerline{a}\centerline{tutti!}`.

I came up with the following code:

`\def\multicenter#1{\def\\{\egroup\centerline\bgroup}\centerline{#1}}`

but it does not work as expected. What's going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\centerline` is a macro with one argument; you can use the “expanded” definition which uses `\line` (that is, `\hbox to \hsize`):

```
\def\multicenter#1{%
  \par
  \bgroup % keep changes local
  \def\\{\hss\egroup\line\bgroup\hss}%
  \line{\hss#1\hss}%
  \egroup
}

\centerline{ciao}
\centerline{a}
\centerline{tutti}

\multicenter{ciao\\a\\tutti}

\bye
```

[image]

Allowing also spaces around `\\`:

```
\def\multicenter#1{%
  \par
  \bgroup % keep changes local
  \def\\{\unskip\hss\egroup\line\bgroup\hss\ignorespaces}%
  \line{\hss#1\hss}%
  \egroup
}

\centerline{ciao}
\centerline{a}
\centerline{tutti}

\multicenter{ciao \\ a \\ tutti}

\bye
```

---

What happens with your macro? Let's try the simpler `\multicenter{ciao\\mondo}`, which becomes

```
\def\\{\egroup\centerline\bgroup}\centerline{ciao\\mondo}}
```

The definition is stored and `\centerline` is expanded according to `\def\centerline#1{\line{\hss#1\hss}}`, so we get

```
\line{\hss ciao\\mondo\hss}
```

that becomes

```
\hbox to \hsize{\hss ciao\\mondo\hss}
```

The box is started and upon expanding `\\` we get (with a few simplifications)

```
\hbox to\hsize{\hss ciao\egroup\centerline\bgroup mondo\hss}
```

So the box is closed and “ciao” will be flush right. Next `\centerline` is expanded, with `\bgroup` as argument, so we have

```
\line{\hss\bgroup\hss}mondo\hss}
```

and so

```
\hbox to\hsize{\hss\bgroup\hss}mondo\hss}
```

The closing brace matches `\bgroup` and you get `mondo` not centered, because of the two `\hss` in front of it.

Note that `\hbox<box specification>{<horizontal material}` allows the horizontal material to be surrounded either by explicit or implicit braces; the braces around a macro argument must always be explicit.

---

Just for fun, here's another solution (it relies on `\parfillskip` having its default value, but it can be easily generalized)

```
\def\multicenter#1{%
  \par
  \begingroup
    \leftskip=\parfillskip \parindent=0pt
    \let\\=\par
    #1\par
  \endgroup
  }
}
```

The difference with the above solution is that here overlong lines will wrap, whereas in the `\hss` based solution above, they will stick in the margins.

An `\halign` based solution that's similar to the `\hss` based one:

```
\def\multicenter#1{%
  \par
  \begingroup
  \let\\=\cr
  \tabskip=0pt plus 1fil
  \halign to\hsize{\hidewidth\ignorespaces##\unskip\hidewidth\cr#1\crcr}
  \endgroup
}
```

Note that both new solutions allow for spaces around `\\`.

Answer (score 7):

You can not surround undelimited (normal) macro arguments with `\bgroup\egroup` you have to use `{}`

I would use an `\halign` something like

```
\def\mcenterline#1{\par{%
   \tabskip0pt plus 1fill
  \let\\\cr\halign to \hsize{\hfill##\hfill\cr#1\crcr}}%
 \par}

\noindent a\dotfill a

\mcenterline{aaa\\bb\\xxx x x x}

\bye
```

---

To see what is wrong with the original consider:

```
\def\multicenter#1{\def\\{\egroup\centerline\bgroup}\centerline{#1}}

\tracingall
\multicenter{aaa\\bb\\xxx x x x}

\bye
```

which produces

```
\multicenter #1->\def \\{\egroup \centerline \bgroup }\centerline {#1}
#1<-aaa\\bb\\xxx x x x
{\def}
{changing \\=macro:#1pt->#1}
{into \\=macro:->\egroup \centerline \bgroup }

\centerline #1->\line {\hss #1\hss }
#1<-aaa\\bb\\xxx x x x

\line ->\hbox to\hsize 
{\hbox}
{entering adjusted hbox group (level 1) at line 4}
{restricted horizontal mode: \hss}
{the letter a}

\\->\egroup \centerline \bgroup 
{end-group character }}
{leaving adjusted hbox group (level 1) entered at line 4}
%% goal height=643.20255, max depth=4.0

\centerline #1->\line {\hss #1\hss }
#1<-\bgroup 

\line ->\hbox to\hsize 
{vertical mode: \hbox}
{entering adjusted hbox group (level 1) at line 4}
{restricted horizontal mode: \hss}
{begin-group character {}
{entering simple group (level 2) at line 4}
{\hss}
{end-group character }}
{leaving simple group (level 2) entered at line 4}
{the letter b}

\\->\egroup \centerline \bgroup 
{end-group character }}
{leaving adjusted hbox group (level 1) entered at line 4}
% t=10.0 g=643.20255 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#

\centerline #1->\line {\hss #1\hss }
#1<-\bgroup 

\line ->\hbox to\hsize 
{vertical mode: \hbox}
{entering adjusted hbox group (level 1) at line 4}
{restricted horizontal mode: \hss}
{begin-group character {}
{entering simple group (level 2) at line 4}
{\hss}
{end-group character }}
{leaving simple group (level 2) entered at line 4}
{the letter x}
{blank space  }
{the letter x}
{blank space  }
{the letter x}
{blank space  }
{the letter x}
{\hss}
{end-group character }}
{leaving adjusted hbox group (level 1) entered at line 4}
% t=22.0 g=643.20255 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
{vertical mode: blank space  }
{\par}
```

Note in particular that `#1` in the `\centerline` is *just* `\bgroup` not all the text between `\bgroup` and `\egroup` so after that the expansion is more or less all accidental and undesired.

Comment: If \bgroup and \endgroup can't be used this way, what does my macro expand to, then?

Comment: @Matteo the wrong thing:-) I'll add a trace to my answer in a second

Comment: @Matteo see updated answer